# `single-row subquery returns more than one row` error unclarity

Tags: sql

I've got two tables. 
The first one hold a type and the second one the value of this type.
In my example if there are more values 'john' as 'first_name' i get:`single-row subquery returns more than one row`

```
SELECT DISTINCT id FROM name WHERE id=(
 SELECT id FROM name WHERE text1='first_name' INTERSECT
 SELECT name_id FROM value WHERE text2='john');
```

I'm not very good with sql. I should use `LEFT JOIN` or something like that but it's not really clear to me how i should do this.

Comment: Your query is bad. But please describe what you want to achive so we can write a good one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the simple fix (using IN instead of id=), you can also use a somewhat simpler version of your query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id FROM name WHERE text1='first_name' 
and id in (
SELECT name_id FROM value WHERE text2='john')
```

Answer (score 3):

Since subquery [can] returns multiple values, `IN` is better use than `=`

```
SELECT DISTINCT id 
FROM name 
WHERE id IN (
        SELECT id FROM name WHERE text1='first_name' 
        INTERSECT
        SELECT name_id FROM value WHERE text2='john');
```

`IN` is equivalent for `OR`, example:

```
SELECT *
FROM tableName
WHERE a = 4 or a = 5 or a = 6
```

can be written as

```
SELECT *
FROM tableName
WHERE a in (4,5,6)
```

The `=` (equal sign) is used to assign single value.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id FROM name WHERE text1='first_name' INTERSECT
SELECT name_id FROM value WHERE text2='john');
```

This query returns more than one row, then you should use `IN` clause like here

```
SELECT DISTINCT id FROM name WHERE id IN (
SELECT id FROM name WHERE text1='first_name' INTERSECT
SELECT name_id FROM value WHERE text2='john');
```

Or if you expect only a row, you have to review your DB's logic and behaviour.

Comment: Then you should include the IN clause in your query ;-)

Answer (score 0):

you could just change
WHERE id=
to 
WHERE id IN

Comment: also you could put a SELECT TOP 1 in - but I'm not sure if you would want to do that?